# Отличается ли JavaScript для Adobe от JavaScript web-страниц?

Tags: pdf, javascript, adobe

У меня есть книжка в pdf, в которой в код зашит масштаб страниц FitWindow, я замучилась каждый раз поправлять масштаб на 100%. Скачала программу JavaScript Editior, он для файлов htm, js и т.д. в общем, pdf открылся в каких-то каракулях, в конце кода я все-таки нашла на англ яз код

> `/AcroForm 2030 0 R/FICL:Enfocus 2021 0 R/Metadata 2026 0 R/Names 2031 0 R/OpenAction 2695 0 R/Outlines 2033 0 R/PageLabels 1963 0 R/PageLayout/SinglePage/PageMode/UseOutlines/Pages 1967 0 R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences<</CenterWindow true/DisplayDocTitle true/**FitWindow true**`

Что мне надо сделать, чтобы запрограммировать вид документа в масштабе 100%? И как сохранить изменения? Потому что я попыталась удалить запись DisplayDocTitle true/FitWindow true и сохранить - изменения не сохранились, ничего в настройках документа не поменялось.

Помогите советом, что делать. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то я не уловил, при чем здесь JavaScript. Это, видимо, вопрос на [БитКод](http://user.hashcode.ru/); а вы пробовали вместо редактирования документа (честно говоря, мне бы это и в голову не пришло) установить масштабирование по умолчанию в просмотрщике PDF? В Foxit Reader, например, есть соответствующая настройка в секции `Preferences -> Page Display.`

Comment: просто эту книжку кто-то уже запрограммировал, чтобы каждая новая страница открывалась в высоту страницы. по стандартным настройкам ( в адоб проф)я смогла поменять только параметры первой страницы при открытии документа, по другим страницам все возвращается на заданные настройки, причем это не фишка адоба -это кто-то реально сделал пакость в документе. В хелпе по адобу предложили поиграться в JavaScript. Вот я и полезла в эти дебри, на самом деле, хочу поправить один документ и все, я на VBA EXCEL программирую нормально, думала по аналогии можно фишечку поправить, но не тут-то было....

Answer (score 0):

Если книга была собрана давно, то и эдоб ридер скачайте примерно того времени, быть может совместимость какая то нарушена в новых версиях со старыми.

Comment: В общем, за это время я нашла отладчик JavaScript в самом адобе, никаких кодов там не оказалась, так что моя теория провалилась. Книжка сама 2010 года, а адоб проф, может, 2011 уже. Не знаю, в чем дело, забила на это все, выучила горячие клавиши - тренирую пальцы :) Спасибо, в любом случае, за ответы.

Comment: Если вам нужен отладчик javascript,  то используйте браузер firefox и дополнение firebug, а если нужен редактор хороший, то вам поможет dreamweaver или notepad plus plus.